# How Scala dataframe filtering OUT?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df, which like below data:

```
|  path |dst|
|1->2->3| 2 |
|1->2->3| 4 |
```

Now I want to filter out where dst **isin** path, So the result df I want as below:

```
|  path |dst|
|1->2->3| 4 |
```

I had try:

```
df.filter(v=>v.getAs[String]("path").split("->").contains(v.getAs[String]("dst")))
```

which return the df that path contain dst, and then I want to use **not**:

```
df.filter(!(v=>v.getAs[String]("path").split("->").contains(v.getAs[String]("dst")))
df.filter(~(v=>v.getAs[String]("path").split("->").contains(v.getAs[String]("dst")))
```

but Idea is red under my code.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
val df = Seq("1->2->3" -> "2", "1->2->3" -> "4").toDF("path", "dst") 
val dstNotInPath = df.filter(!array_contains(split($"path", "->"), $"dst"))

dstNotInPath.show

dstNotInPath: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [path: 
string, dst: string]
+-------+---+
|   path|dst|
+-------+---+
|1->2->3|  4|
+-------+---+
```

Now, let's learn how to fish:

1. create a suitable dataframe (it wasn't mentioned in your question)
2. define what you want to do, **with typing**:

- split a string column into an array of strings
- test if this array contains the value of another column
- invert test (and filter)

3. look on internet of each of these operations

- split string into array -> I found the `split` method, and an example of how to use it
- test if array contains: found `array_contains` and an example
- invert test was as you mentioned

Note:

- Here I use the "dataframe api", where I declare symbolically what operations on the dataframe columns need to be done. This is recommended for such operations (filtering on a `type Dataframe = Dataset[Row]` objects)
- You use the "rdd api" where you apply a scala function on each `Row` type entry of the dataframe. It means that the function is serialized, send to each worker, and executed there on the java/scala `Row` instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```scala
df2.filter(v=> !v.getAs[String]("path").split("->").contains(v.getAs[String]("dst")))
```

Or solution with DataFrame API:

```scala
    df.withColumn("splitted_path",functions.split($"path", "->"))
      .withColumn("filter_c",array_contains($"splitted_path", $"dst"))
      .where(!$"filter_c")
      .drop("splitted_path","filter_c")
```